# Alpha channel transparency and resizing image files

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, gdi+

I'm using the following code to resize a tif. The tif has an alpha channel set for transparency. I'm trying to resize this image and honour the transparency but at the moment it's coming out with a black background. Any ideas?

```
public static void ResizeImage(string OriginalImagePath, string NewImagePath, int Width, int Height)
        {
            Size NewSize = new Size(Width, Height);

            using (Image OriginalImage = Image.FromFile(OriginalImagePath))
            {
                //Graphics objects can not be created from bitmaps with an Indexed Pixel Format, use RGB instead.
                PixelFormat Format = OriginalImage.PixelFormat;
                if (Format.ToString().Contains("Indexed"))
                    Format = PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb;

                using (Bitmap NewImage = new Bitmap(NewSize.Width, NewSize.Height, OriginalImage.PixelFormat))
                {
                    using (Graphics Canvas = Graphics.FromImage(NewImage))
                    {
                        Canvas.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                        Canvas.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                        Canvas.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                        Canvas.DrawImage(OriginalImage, new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), NewSize));
                        NewImage.Save(NewImagePath, OriginalImage.RawFormat);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: 1) What is the value of OriginalImage.PixelFormat for the images you're having trouble with? 2) Try to save to a PNG instead. Does that still give you black pixels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found out that due to the way the transparency is stored in the tiff format with photoshop it was better to create png's by automating photoshop and then crunching off the resulting png.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (Format.ToString().Contains("Indexed"))
    Format = PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb;
```

`Format32bppArgb` specifies an alpha channel in the pixel format.

And I think you meant to do this:

```
using (Bitmap NewImage = new Bitmap(NewSize.Width, NewSize.Height, Format))
```

***EDIT:***

Actually, try just forcing the pixel format on the `NewImage` to `Format32bppArgb` like so:

```
using (Bitmap NewImage = new Bitmap(NewSize.Width, NewSize.Height,
    PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
```

Comment: Tried the changes you suggested, it's still coming though with the black background.

Answer (score 0):

```
Canvas.Clear(Color.Transparent)
```

before you blit.

Comment: And did you set the pixel format of the new bitmap to Format32bppRgb as Codesleuth suggested? You will not get transparency with 24 bit color, there is no alpha channel.